# Is Android Executor instance executing time-consuming tasks still kept alive after the Main Activity is destroyed?

Tags: android, lifecycle, executor

If I create an Android Executor as a member of the application singleton and then in the Main Activity I use the executor to do some time-consuming tasks such as writing big amount of data to the database, will the database operation be still finished if I pressed the back button to exit the App or swipe to exit from the running application list? 
A further question is that, even if the executor is kept alive till completion, what will happen if the execute() routine did access some Activity's member variables, which would be gone after destroy?